# fluent Nhibernatetest mappings

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dns, fluent-nhibernate, domain-driven-design

Hi there 
I am using Fluent Nhibernate and I'd like to write tests for my mappings as shown below.

I have a scenario where I have a User class and a UserProfile class

The User class is an entity and the UserProfile is a value type, there is a 1:1 relationship between the two.

How would I test the mappings based on this? Do I write separate tests for User and UserProfile? or Am I able to write a test for User that maps the profile at the same time? 
Thanks

```
[Test] 
public void can_correctly_map_customer()
{
    new PersistenceSpecification<Customer>(Session)
    .CheckProperty(c => c.Id, 1001)
    .CheckProperty(c => c.FirstName, "John")
    .CheckProperty(c => c.LastName, "Doe")
}
```

Comment: you should fix your post.  You've ended your pre or code too early I think?

Answer (score 1):

[Persistence specification testing](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Persistence_specification_testing)

See the section on testing references.